# How to check if a JSON object is present in a file in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, react-native

I am building an app in react-native and have been trouble getting some trouble doing error checking. I am using `redux` and `thunk` to store a JSON file from the API that I am searching from. Sometimes, the search will lead back with a JSON file that contains an error message(most likely due to spelling error or unsure about what I am exactly searching for). I am trying to build a function in my app that will run in an `componentWillMount` function that first checks if the file has an error meassage and if so will send it back to the home screen to redo the search. The problem that am encountering is that I do not know what to code inorder to see what the error is or even if there is an error to begin with.

this is what the error object will look like in the JSON file and this

```
"error": {
    "type": "NameResolutionException",
    "message": "Name resolution error: Taxon 'Mallard' or 'Bat' resolve to multiple nodes"
  },
```

This is the function that I built

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    console.log("STATE", this.state);
    if(this.props.response.articles.error == undefined){
      if(this.props.response.articles.error.type === "NameResolutionException"){
        Alert.alert("Please Refine Search or Specify Taxon.")
          .then(()=>this.props.navigation.navigate("Home"));
      }
    }
 };
```

The if statements will never hit despite the fact that the json file will the error object in it.

The expected output is that the error will be caught and then the app will go back to its the home screen but instead the app will fail because certain components will be missing.

Comment: I'll bet `articles` is an array, not an object, so you need to index it.

Comment: Hope there should be `!= undefined` in first `if`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems not correct, you are saying if error is undefined then comparing for a string value. This is contradictory.

It should be something like this, considering error is an object not an array

```
componentDidMount = () => {
console.log("STATE", this.state);
if(this.props.response.articles.error && this.props.response.articles.error.type){ // considering error object may or may not be present
  if(this.props.response.articles.error.type === "NameResolutionException"){
    Alert.alert("Please Refine Search or Specify Taxon.")
      .then(()=>this.props.navigation.navigate("Home"));
  }
  else if (this.props.response.articles.error.type === "OtherPossibleStringException"){
  }
  else {
      //Any unhandled error case
  }
 }
};
```